# Can we use ASP.NET Boilerplate with Dapper instead of Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core, dapper, aspnetboilerplate

I'm new to ASP.NET Boilerplate and Dapper. From the tutorial I got to know that ASP.NET Boilerplate works with Entity Framework Core. Can we use another Data Access Layer instead of EF Core? Is ASP.NET Boilerplate compatible with Dapper?

Answer (score 2):

Sure! you can use Dapper.

**Installation**

Before you start, you need to install https://www.nuget.org/packages/Abp.Dapper, either EF Core, EF 6.x or the NHibernate ORM NuGet packages into the project you want to use.

---

**Module Registration**

First, you need to add the DependsOn attribute for the AbpDapperModule on your *application* module where you register it

```
[DependsOn(
     typeof(AbpEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
     typeof(AbpDapperModule)
)]
public class MyApplicationModule: AbpModule
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(MyApplicationModule).GetAssembly());
    }
}
```

---

**Entity to Table Mapping**

You can configure mappings. For example, the Person class maps to the *Person* table in the following example:

```
public class PersonMapper: ClassMapper<Person>
{
    public PersonMapper()
    {
        Table("Persons");
        Map(x => x.Roles).Ignore();
        AutoMap();
    }
}
```

---

**Sample Application Module**:

```
[DependsOn(
     typeof(AbpEntityFrameworkModule),
     typeof(AbpDapperModule)
)]
public class SampleApplicationModule: AbpModule
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(SampleApplicationModule).GetAssembly());
        DapperExtensions.SetMappingAssemblies(new List<Assembly> { typeof(SampleApplicationModule).GetAssembly() });
    }
}
```

---

**Usage**

After registering AbpDapperModule, you can use the Generic IDapperRepository interface (instead of standard IRepository) to inject dapper repositories.

```
public class SomeApplicationService : ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IDapperRepository<Person> _personDapperRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<Person> _personRepository;

    public SomeApplicationService(
        IRepository<Person> personRepository,
        IDapperRepository<Person> personDapperRepository)
    {
        _personRepository = personRepository;
        _personDapperRepository = personDapperRepository;
    }

    public void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        var people = _personDapperRepository.Query("select * from Persons");
    }
}
```

---

Check out these links:

- https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dapper-Integration
- https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/1854#issuecomment-284511423
- https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/1854#issuecomment-284639277
- [Trying to set up a Dapper-based Data Access Layer. ABP.Dapper documentation is confusing and incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51678094/trying-to-set-up-a-dapper-based-data-access-layer-abp-dapper-documentation-is-c)